# Comic where aliens and their craft are melted by the intense heat of Antarctic (or Arctic) ice

Tags: story-identification, aliens, comics

I remember a short comic featuring a flying saucer crewed by two aliens with inky black bodies (visible where not covered by their clothes) deciding whether or not to land on (prehistoric?) Earth. One crew says that the planet is far too hot for the ship and crew to survive a landing. The other, perhaps a jet-fuel-can’t-melt-steel-beams kind of being, says that the polar regions should be safe enough.

The craft lands on some polar ice and is quickly destroyed by the intense heat, first by structural failure, then by explosion, ultimately melting the two aliens, leaving two black puddles on the ice.

An Earth scientist finds and collects the black goo for analysis. (I do not remember if remnants of the craft existed and were noticed by the scientist.)

At his laboratory at home, he accidentally spills or splashes some of the goo, which burns, digests or chemically attacks his exposed skin. His 1950s housewife immediately tips the remainder of the stuff down a sink. He then scolds his wife for dumping an unknown substance into the drain where it will reach the ocean with unknown ecological effects.

The last panel is of a growing black slick in the ocean. The narration text informs the reader that if they look closely, they will perceive the slick getting larger.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Where and when did you read this?  Was it black and white or colour?

Comment: @DavidW, it was a CMYK colour strip in a comic book issue similar in physical form to a 2000AD issue, say. I read it in the late 70s or early 80s. It was part of a fairy random collection of comics and fragments of comic books (Including Pop-eye, Dr Who and Nineteen Eighty-four) I somehow acquired as a young adolescent. Some of the comics were from an assorted stash in my grandmother’s house. (I mention CMYK because some of the comics I read used older colour printing methods.)

Comment: Sounds like a one shot from a Sci-Fi tales type comic. Like "Planet Comics" or "Tales of the Unexpected" or "Mystery in Space"

Comment: This reminds me of, but is almost certainly not (unless there was a novelization/comic of it) the Black Goo from X-Files.